# Ruby SQLite adapter fails when using escape characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am using the sqlite3 adapter for Ruby and getting some strange behavior. I am using `?` to escape input into my queries. The following works:

```
db.execute 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ?', 1 
  => [{ "id"=> 1, "name" => "Hannah" }]
db.execute 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = ?, 'Hannah'
  => [{ "id"=> 1, "name" => "Hannah" }]
db.execute 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 1 AND name = ?', 'Hannah' 
  => [{ "id"=> 1, "name" => "Hannah" }]
```

The following, however, does not work:

```
db.execute 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ? AND name = ?', 1, 'Hannah' 
  => []
```

Why is this?

Comment: What query is generated? Post that too.

Comment: How can I view that information?

Comment: What happens if you try this: `db.execute "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ? AND name = '?'", 1, 'Hannah' 
`

Comment: I get the same error. It turns out that, when using multiple parameters, you must pass an array. It is completely undocumented. 

https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/commit/43dd1e0024aa33efbc293303859a61e6ccb69a23

Comment: Do you have variables? Otherwise why not using the values directly inside the query ?

Comment: Did you try ? `db.execute 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ? AND name = ?', [1, 'Hannah']` .. This should work..

Comment: What do you mean by "completely undocumented"? I'd say that [`execute(sql, bind_vars = [], *args, &block)`](http://rubydoc.org/github/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3/Database:execute) is pretty clear about what `bind_vars` is supposed to be. Granted, the docs aren't exactly great but they're about on par with Ruby documentation in general.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes..you are right..

Comment: @muistooshort From the documentation: `Executes the given SQL statement. If additional parameters are given, they are treated as bind variables, and are bound to the placeholders in the query.` The method signature contains `*args` which implies, to me, that you can pass in varargs for the bind variables. Also, on Rubyforge, which is the first Google result (http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/sqlite3/faq.html), it says you can pass in varargs for the placeholders.

Comment: Like I said, the docs aren't exactly great but the signature says `bind_vars = []`. Also, `args` are only used if `bind_vars.nil?` but, as is often the case in Ruby land, you have to read the source code to know that.